# No generic method 'Sum' on type 'System.Linq.Enumerable' is compatible

Tags: c#, linq, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I am having some issues with the MVC Wrappers for Kendo UI.  It seems that IEnumerable does not support any aggregate values other than count.  The exception that I get is:
No generic method 'Sum' on type 'System.Linq.Enumerable' is compatible with the supplied type arguments and arguments. No type arguments should be provided if the method is non-generic.

I am not sure how to get around this issues nor am I sure if it is a flaw with Kendo.

**Please note that the aggregate function used below is not LINQ per say but what Kendo UI's wrapper provides as a function.  Please see [Kendo UI Documentation](http://docs.kendoui.com/getting-started/using-kendo-with/aspnet-mvc/helpers/grid/configuration) for more information.**

**Data Source:**

- Northwind

**Controller:**

```
public ActionResult Index() { return View(); }
public ActionResult Read([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request) { return GetView(request); }
private IEnumerable<dynamic> GetData() { var db = new NwEntities(); return db.Products; }
private JsonResult GetView(DataSourceRequest request) { return Json(GetData().ToDataSourceResult(request)); }
```

**View:**

```
@model IEnumerable<dynamic>
@(
 Html.Kendo().Grid(Model).Name("Grid")
    .DataSource(ds =>
        ds.Ajax()
        .Model(m =>
        {
            m.Id("ProductID");
            m.Field("ProductName", typeof(string));
            m.Field("UnitPrice", typeof(decimal));
        })
        .Aggregates(aggregate => aggregate.Add(a => "UnitPrice").Count().Sum())
        .Read(r => r.Action("Read", "Home"))
    )
    .Columns(columns =>
    {
        columns.Bound("ProductID");
        columns.Bound("ProductName");
        columns.Bound("UnitPrice").Format("{0:c}");
    })
    .Groupable()
)
```

Comment: `.Count().Sum()` -- `.Aggregates(...)` -- these just aren't valid.

Comment: I guess this is caused by your `IEnumerable<dynamic>`. Why do you use `IEnumerable<dynamic>` at all? Also I don't know whether the KendoUI wrappers support it... So try to crate a Product class with the proeprties ProductID, ProductName, UnitPrice to see whether it works.

Comment: @TimothyShields The `.Count().Sum()` not the Linq methods but the configuration API of the Kendo UI grid. See the [documentation.](http://docs.kendoui.com/getting-started/using-kendo-with/aspnet-mvc/helpers/grid/configuration)

Comment: ProductID,ProductName,UnitPrice is just an example.  The actual project I am on has 265 columns but the user gets to select the columns in a report builder.  Returning 265 columns to the grid and hiding the others was detrimental to performance so I have to dynamically select the columns.  That is why I have to use dynamic.

Comment: Is [this](http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/wpf/chart/error-in-aplying-aggregate-function-when-binding-from-datatable.aspx) relevant?

Comment: @CodeCaster I tried that already and it was a no-go.

Comment: As @nemesv mentioned, Count().Sum() is a perfectly valid Aggregate with KendoUI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is now an known issue with Kendo UI and will be fixed by the Kendo UI team

Answer (score 0):

@MitchellSkurnik received an asnwer [here](http://www.telerik.com/forums/no-generic-method-sum-on-type-system-linq-enumerable-is-compatible).

Answer (score -1):

Sum with no arguments only works on IEnumerables of the built in types decimal, double, int, etc.

To call it with a generic type, you must provide a transform function.

I.e.

```
enumerable.Sum(e => e.Value)
```

where e.Value is what you want to sum.

Also see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.sum.aspx

Comment: This is Kendos Sum() function and not LINQ

Comment: @MitchellSkurnik the error message is about 'System.Linq.Enumerable'. The compiler is telling you where the error is coming from, and you refuse to listen to anyone telling you otherwise. Your library may be using these methods under the hood without your knowledge. Either way, .Count().Sum() doesn't make any sense.

Comment: These are from Kendo UI.  .Count().Sum() add an aggregate that is returned as JSON.

Comment: @MitchellSkurnik Like I said above, you might be using some 3rd party API, but the Count and Sum methods are the ones from System.Linq namespaces. **The API you're using is in turn using Linq.** The compiler directly says this in the error message. You're not going to get another answer because those methods aren't coming from your 3rd party API. You are trying to call .Count().Sum() **which doesn't make any sense.** The documentation you linked **does not provide a Count or Sum method and is using the Linq ones.**